# When i input a value into my code, another (assumed ascii) value is used. E.G: input 7, output 55. How do i fix it?

Tags: c#

Console.WriteLine("below enter a value to be converted to scientific notation");
                Console.WriteLine("~ enter any letter to end program ~ \n");

```
            int y = Convert.ToInt32(Console.Read());
            Console.WriteLine(y);

            if (y >= 1 && y <= 10)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("val [ {0} ] is in valid form", y);
            }
            else if (y > 10)
            {
                Upp(y);
            }
            else if (y < 1)
            {
                Low(y);
            }
```

Comment: Hello, @Jake Ward. Welcome to StackOverflow. You haven't really asked anything in your question; it's just a title and code sample. If you could edit your post to ask your question, I'm sure someone will be happy to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Console.Read() reads a character and when a character is use in Convert.ToInt32() it outputs the ASCII value. Use Console.ReadLine() to get a string. When using a string with Convert.ToInt32() you will get the result you are looking for.

```
Console.WriteLine(Console.Read()); // Input 7 output 55
Console.WriteLine(Console.ReadLine()); // Input 7 output 7
```

Comment: It's misleading to use a term like "ASCII value". For text datatypes, .NET uses the UTF-16 character encoding of the Unicode character set (as does Java, JavaScript, VB4/5/6/A/Script, …).